# Sliders (MenuCool Slider to be exact)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I was wondering if it was at all possible to create a slider which had checkboxes and showed the next slide depending on which check box was ticked.

For example:

*Generic Question*

Yes     No

If you click Yes then you move onto the next question. If you click No then you get taken to a different slide.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no slider that providing the same option. But We can develop such sliders using Jquery OR Javascript

Or We can customize an existing slider.

Comment: Ok, I'm a total beginner but how would i go about developing this?

Comment: Do you know jquery Or Javascript ? If you wish to develop such a tool. You should have knowledge in html,css and jquery. You can observe the working of another image slider for the same